# Disabling output of ROS

Tags: ros, rosout, rospy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am getting a great amount of [ INFO] messages when i run a rospy script. I am wondering if there is a way to disable them.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/268073/disabling-output-of-ros/) by [kchledowski](https://answers.ros.org/users/31224/kchledowski/) on ROS Answers with karma: 52 on 2017-08-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

See:
http://wiki.ros.org/rosconsole#Configuration

The default File is placed in:

/opt/ros/kinetic/share/ros/config/rosconsole.config

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2017-08-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kchledowski](https://answers.ros.org/users/31224/kchledowski/) on 2017-08-07**:
Thank you very much, that is exactly what I was looking for! :)